# Como acessar parametro de rota dinamica Vue-Router

Tags: laravel-5, template, vue.js

Usando o vue-router, me deparei com um problema, quando pesso uma rota dinamica, do tipo

```
{ path: '/horario/:dia/:hora', component: Bar },
```

acontece um problema, n consigo acessar os valores de dia e hora na pagina destino, isto pq ela é um template, porem, preciso desta informação, estou usando um template file .vue.

Ele é:

```
<template>
   <div></div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log(dia);
            console.log(hora);
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },
        data(){
            return {

            }
        } 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Sabes como compilar ficheiros `.vue` num só para o Vue usar? Depois dentro do componente basta usar o `$route`, por exemplo dentro do `mounted` podes ter `console.log(this.$route.params);`

Comment: Sei, porem, os numeros ficam da seguinte forma, ":n", sendo que n é o numero, gostaria apenas de ter o n sem fazer um parse.

Comment: Podes montar um exemplo que reproduza isso? Fico com duvidas se percebi o problema.

Comment: Resolvido, Eu que tava usando um link na forma de http://(link_site)/horario/:3/:4, sendo que só precisava do numero

Answer (score 1):

Você pode acessar os parâmetros da rota através do [`$route`](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html), dessa forma:

```
mounted() {
    console.log(this.$route.params.dia);
    console.log(this.$route.params.hora);
    console.log('Component mounted.')
},
```

É importante observar que depois de `params` você vai chamar o nome que você registrou no path **(sem os dois pontos)**, no seu caso dia e hora:

- { path: '/horario/:**dia**/:**hora**', component: Bar }

Logo o resultado da URL /horario/10/20 seria:

```
mounted() {
    console.log(this.$route.params.dia); // 10
    console.log(this.$route.params.hora); // 20
},
```